# delete data from the database using symfony

Tags: php, database, forms, symfony, crud

I just started learning symfony for the past couple of weeks and i've been trying to create a form to delete users from my database but the code that i've wrote doesnt work and i don't undertand what I've been doing wrong. if anyone see the issue thank you in advance.

```
     /**
     * @Route("/utilisateur/retirer", name="user_remove", methods={"GET","POST", "DELETE"})
     * @return Response
     **/
    public function removeUser( ManagerRegistry $doctrine, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response 
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class);
        $em = $doctrine->getManager();
        $user = $doctrine->getRepository(User::class);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em->remove($user);
            $em->flush();        
        }
         return $this->render('back_office/user_remove.html.twig',[
             'form' => $form->createView()
         ]);
    }
```

Comment: This line `$user = $doctrine->getRepository(User::class);` returns the `UserRepository`, not a `User` object. You can use the `UserRepository` to find the `User` object that you want to delete, but depending on how your `UserType` form is set up, you may also be able to get the `User` object directly from the form. Could you show your `UserType` form?

Comment: Why not dump the variables you are using to check for problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way you've done : your user variable is the user repository not the user entity

You need to get user Entity.

Either you can send the id of user than find the user like this  :

```
 $user = $doctrine->getRepository(User::class)->find($request->get('id'))
```

or you can pass the user id via parameter in url :

url : "/utilisateur/retirer/{id}"

parameters :  User $user

```
/**
     * @Route("/utilisateur/retirer/{id}", name="user_remove", methods={"GET","POST", "DELETE"})
     * @return Response
     **/
    public function removeUser(User $user, ManagerRegistry $doctrine, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response 
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class);
        $em = $doctrine->getManager();
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em->remove($user);
            $em->flush();        
        }
         return $this->render('back_office/user_remove.html.twig',[
             'form' => $form->createView()
         ]);
    }
```

In aim of making more secure you can try this code bellow :

Controller :

```
 /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="user_delete", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function delete(Request $request, User $user): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$user->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->remove($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_index', Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }
```

Form :

```
<form method="post" class="position-absolute  ms-5" action="{{ path('user_delete', {'id': user.id}) }}" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token('delete' ~ user.id) }}">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```